# Запросы к серверу на js

Tags: javascript, python

У меня есть скрипт на python, который одновременно является ботом для telegram и база данных с пользователями (json), с которой работает скрипт. Я бы хотел разделить сам скрипт и бота. То есть, сделать так, чтобы бот просто посылал запросы к скрипту, чтобы он, в свою очередь выполнял какие-то действия с бд. Как эти запросы можно реализовать?

Comment: Http очевидный первый выбор

Comment: Но вообще непонятно в чём собственно проблема. Вотпрос какой-то слишком абстрактный